# Independent Kafka Spark Sinks (multiple producers and brokers)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, bigdata, spark-streaming

So I have a problem with Kafka Sinks in Spark Streaming while sending JSONs to multiple topics and **unreliable kafka brokers**. Here are some parts of code:

```
val kS = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, TMapRecord]
(ssc,
PreferConsistent,
Subscribe[String, TMapRecord](topicsSetT, kafkaParamsInT))
```

Then I iterate over RDD's

```
kSMapped.foreachRDD {
  rdd: RDD[TMsg] => {
    rdd.foreachPartition {
      part => {
        part.foreach { ...........
```

And inside foreach I do

```
kafkaSink.value.send(kafkaTopic, strJSON)

kafkaSinkMirror.value.send(kafkaTopicMirrorBroker, strJSON)
```

When **Mirror broker** is down the entire Streaming Application is waiting for it and we are not sending anything to the main broker.

How would you handle it?

For the easiest solution you propose, imagine that me just skip messages that were meant to be sent to a broker that went down (say, that's CASE 1)

for the CASE 2 we'd do some buffering.

P.S. Later on I will use Kafka Mirror, but currently I don't have such an option so I need to make some solution in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I've found several decisions of this problem:

1. You may use throwing any timeout exception on worker and [checkpoints](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing). Spark tries to restart bad task several times described in `spark.task.maxFailures` property. It is possible to increase number of retries. If streaming job fails after max retries, just will restart the job from checkpoint when broker is available. Or you could [manually stop the job when it fails](https://venkateshiyer.net/production-ready-spark-streaming-a8d85b7d66be).
2. You could configure [backpressure](https://www.inovex.de/blog/247-spark-streaming-on-yarn-in-production/) `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true` that allow to receive data only as fast as it can process it.
3. You could send you two results back to your technical Kafka topic and handle it later with another streaming job.
4. You could make Hive or Hbase buffer for this cases and send unhandled data later in batch mode.

Comment: 1. It won't solve the problem. If it fails in that case it will restart from some checkpoint but won't go any further and won't send messages to the main broker while the second broker is down

Comment: 2. How it solves the problem? 3. Our kafka broker is overloaded, that's not an option. 4. Buffer needs to be managed On-Line, in which case it's more likely to have an HBase buffer table. But the implementation looks a bit complicated

Comment: Point 4 describes how. Just put fails in for example Hbase like pairs (kafkaTopic, dataToSend) and send them later.